# How to translate ObjectStateEntry.OriginalValues into Entity?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

How to translate ObjectStateEntry.OriginalValues into Entity?
I thought I can do this with `ObjectContext.Translate` method but I have to pass DataReader instead. Is there any ways?

Comment: I need audit history of entity

Comment: that is way I need original state

Answer (score 3):

In order to convert `OriginalValues` to an `Entity` object you can use reflection over the properties (you have the names buried in `OriginalValues.DataRecordInfo.FieldMetadata[i].FieldType.Name`). What are you planning to do afterwards, however? Compare the entities property-by-property? It would be easier to get the list of modified properties directly:

```
var originalValues = yourEntry.OriginalValues;
var currentValues = yourEntry.CurrentValues;
var modifiedProperties = yourEntry.GetModifiedProperties();

foreach (var modifiedProperty in modifiedProperties)
{
    LogChange(string.Format("Property: {0}, Original value: {1}, Current value: {2}", 
                            modifiedProperty,
                            originalValues[modifiedProperty],
                            currentValues[modifiedProperty])
    );
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement the `OnSomePropertyChanging` methods for your entity objects and log the changes in real time:

```
public partial class YourEntity
{
    partial void OnSomePropertyChanging(string value)
    {
        LogChange(String.Format("Property: SomeProperty, Original value: {0}, Current value: {1}, Change time: {2}", 
                  this.SomeProperty,
                  value,
                  DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString())
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool answer, I like your extended method.